# creating new window from inside a class is merging content to the parent window in tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a new window from within a window in Tkinter but all my new content is added to the parent window, not in the new window.

[the first window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPqhp.png)

[the second window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fffHF.png)

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
import tkinter as tk

NORMAL_PADDING = 3


class AllPages(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.font = font.Font(family='JetBrains Mono', name='jbm', size=12, weight='normal')

        self.posts = [
            {
                "title": "huhu"
            }
        ]

        self.posts_container = tk.Frame()

        for post in self.posts:
            postf = tk.Frame(self.posts_container, bg="#ffffff", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
            post_t = tk.Label(postf, text=post["title"], bg="#ffffff", borderwidth=0, font=self.font)
            post_edit = tk.Button(postf, text="Edit", bg="#ffffff", borderwidth=0, relief="solid", highlightbackground="#ffffff", highlightcolor="#ffffff", highlightthickness=1, font=self.font, command= lambda: self.modify_post_form(post))
            post_t.pack(side="left")
            post_edit.pack(side="right")
            postf.pack(anchor=W, fill='x', pady=NORMAL_PADDING)
        
        self.posts_container.pack(fill='both', ipadx=NORMAL_PADDING, padx=NORMAL_PADDING)

    def modify_post_form(self, post):
        newW = Toplevel()
        app = CreatePostForm(newW)



class CreatePostForm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, post=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        if not ("jbm" in font.names()):
            self.font = font.Font(family='JetBrains Mono', name='jbm', size=12, weight='normal')
        else:
            self.font = font.nametofont("jbm")

        self.label_width = 20
        self.input_width = 40

        self.title_container = tk.Frame()
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self.title_container, text="Title:", font=self.font, width=self.label_width, anchor=W)
        self.title_input = tk.Entry(self.title_container, width=self.input_width, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", font=self.font)

        self.title_label.pack(side="left")
        self.title_input.pack(side="right")
        self.title_container.pack(anchor=W, pady=NORMAL_PADDING)

        self.title = tk.StringVar()

        self.title_input["textvariable"] = self.title


root = tk.Tk()
myapp = AllPages(root)
myapp.pack()
myapp.mainloop()
```

The first window is created by the `AllPages()` class. then `AllPages().modify_post_form()` creates a new window using `Toplevel()` and pass it to `CreatePostForm()` class. `CreatePostForm()` should then populates the new window with some new content but whatever `CreatePostForm()` creates is going to the parent window, not to the new window created using `Toplevel()`.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You are either failing to pass the parent container when creating your widgets, or are passing something with a value of None (which is interpreted as meaning the root window).  I can't be more specific, because you somehow failed to include a single example of a wrong-parented widget in the code you posted.

Comment: When I add in enough code to make your example work, the widgets created in `CreatePostForm` appear in the `Toplevel` as expected. Please make sure the code you posted actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: please check the [the first window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPqhp.png) and [the second window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fffHF.png) image.  the first window has one frame with a button named "Edit" on clicking that button a new window should be created with some content in it but instead of going to the new window, it's going to the first window. see the second image. everything after the first frame (that has "huhu    Edit") should go to the small window at the top.

Comment: The code in your question won't create either of those images. Please make sure your question includes a working [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley thank you. please check the question now.

Comment: As the first comment said, you need to specify the *parent* of widget, otherwise it will be the *root* window.  Note that the line `self.title_container = tk.Frame()` inside `CreatePostForm` class will create the frame inside the *root* window instead of the toplevel window because you did not specify the parent in `tk.Frame()`.

Comment: Ok. I understood my problem. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the above code is that both `class`es didn't specify the window it should create content into. Here is the working code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
import tkinter as tk

NORMAL_PADDING = 3


class AllPages(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.font = font.Font(family='JetBrains Mono', name='jbm', size=12, weight='normal')

        self.posts = [
            {
                "title": "huhu"
            }
        ]

        self.posts_container = tk.Frame(self)

        for post in self.posts:
            postf = tk.Frame(self.posts_container, bg="#ffffff", borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
            post_t = tk.Label(postf, text=post["title"], bg="#ffffff", borderwidth=0, font=self.font)
            post_edit = tk.Button(postf, text="Edit", bg="#ffffff", borderwidth=0, relief="solid", highlightbackground="#ffffff", highlightcolor="#ffffff", highlightthickness=1, font=self.font, command= lambda: self.modify_post_form(post))
            post_t.pack(side="left")
            post_edit.pack(side="right")
            postf.pack(anchor=W, fill='x', pady=NORMAL_PADDING)
        
        self.posts_container.pack(fill='both', ipadx=NORMAL_PADDING, padx=NORMAL_PADDING)

    def modify_post_form(self, post):
        newW = Toplevel()
        app = CreatePostForm(newW)



class CreatePostForm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, post=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        if not ("jbm" in font.names()):
            self.font = font.Font(family='JetBrains Mono', name='jbm', size=12, weight='normal')
        else:
            self.font = font.nametofont("jbm")

        self.label_width = 20
        self.input_width = 40

        self.title_container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self.title_container, text="Title:", font=self.font, width=self.label_width, anchor=W)
        self.title_input = tk.Entry(self.title_container, width=self.input_width, borderwidth=1, relief="solid", font=self.font)

        self.title_label.pack(side="left")
        self.title_input.pack(side="right")
        self.title_container.pack(anchor=W, pady=NORMAL_PADDING)

        self.title = tk.StringVar()

        self.title_input["textvariable"] = self.title


root = tk.Tk()
myapp = AllPages(root)
myapp.pack()
myapp.mainloop()
```

Thank you to all the people who commented and helped me.